# SQL Server Data Tools - Auto Deploy

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, deployment, version-control, sql-server-data-tools

I have a windows forms application that I want to distribute online for small businesses.

The application will will run on several stations in a local network.

The application will check for online updates and update itself automatically.

The database update must occur only once after a user update the application in one of the stations.

**Is there any built-in way to distribute and run the database updates automatically using database projects with SSDT?**

Comment: As Kevin noted - no way to do this automatically out of the box, but there are ways to code it in. You may want to look at having a DB Version table of some sort as well. Check that prior to the DB build and only run if the version is < what is expected. There are a handful of ways to do that, usually with some sort of "Version" table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core engine used by SSDT to update is called DacFx (Data Tier Application Framework). This is redistributable, and if you choose to include it and its dependents in your application then you could download a .dacpac with the database changes and have your app run [DacServices.Deploy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacservices.deploy(v=sql.130).aspx) (or call into SqlPackage.exe) to update the database on upgrade of your application. The latest DacFramework.msi and dependencies are below.

[DacFramework installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51238) (February 2016)
Dependencies (SQL Server 2016 RC0):

- [SQLSysCLRTypes.msi](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=730592&clcid=0x409) x64
- [SQLSysCLRTypes.msi](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=730604&clcid=0x409) x86
- [SQLDOM.msi](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=730588&clcid=0x409) x64
- [SQLDOM.msi](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=730600&clcid=0x409) x86

Comment: Hi @Kevin, so, i will have to install on my x86 installer:

DacFramework + SQLDOMx86 + SQLSysCLRTypes86 ? 

There is some "complete" msi?

Comment: Currently it is 3 different MSIs. We are looking to simplify as we move these components to no longer be GAC'd (globally installed), but for now this is the safest way. In the future we'd hope to give you a nuget package with exactly the components you need, but we don't have a clear date on this.

Comment: For this reference (Microsoft.Sql.Dac) work properly on my project with these installations, how should I reference it?

Comment: C:\Program Files [(x86)]\Microsoft SQL Server\[SQL Version]\DAC\bin, there is a way to reference it for any sql version, including x64 ?  Should I Copy Local?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. The 130 version supports SQL Server 2005-2016 and all versions in between. Copy Local is a good idea. Please note that if you want to redistribute it's important to include the License.txt file laid down on disk, as that's what allows you to do this.